# Converting GAMS to Julia JuMP: Defining sets

Tags: optimization, julia, julia-jump

I want to convert GAMS code to Julia JuMP, and I have problems dealing with the sets in GAMS.

Here is the constraint in GAMS:
eDemIR(d)… demIReal(d) + sum(l,line2dem(l,d)*lineIReal(l)) =e= 0;

l, d are sets in GAMS. l = [1,2,3] and d = [1,2,3,4,5]

What is the proper way of converting this to JuMP?

Thanks!

This is how I tried to define every set in the constraint:
D = [1,2,3,4,5]
L = [1,2,3]
@constraint(model, eDemIR[d in D], demIReal[d in D] + sum(line2dem[l, d] * lineIReal[l] for l in L) == 0)

Answer (score 0):

In Jump "sets" are just standard indexes that you use for your data and/or variables... can be positions if you use arrays, or keys if you use dictionaries.

Have a look at my tutorial where I translate to Jump the classical Gams `transport` tutorial:

https://lobianco.org/antonello/personal/blog/2017/0203_jump_for_gams_users

Comment: Thanks @Antonello, I have already read your tutorial. Can you tell if this is correct : sum(line2dem[l, d] * lineIReal[l] for l in L) == 0) in the constraint ? or should we write sum(line2dem[l, d] * lineIReal[l] for l in L, d in D) == 0)

Comment: It depends if in your model  you need a _family_ of constraint, one for each `d`, (first case) or a single constraint (second case)

Comment: I need the whole cases for D = [1,2,3,4,5] L = [1,2,3]

Comment: So you need a single constraint, a single sum for all the cases, equal to zero. In that case the second expression you wrote is correct. You don't need to parametrize the constraint then, just give it a name and the constraint expression.